# XSD.exe - How to initialize a type created from xs:choice

Tags: c#, serialization, xsd.exe

I'm fairly new to working with XSD's and serialization de-serialization, I'm looking for some advice on how to initialise the resulting class object created from a xs:choice element in the XSD, to start here's some info on the XSD and Object class:

*Examples taken from a larger XSD, object class.*

XSD:

```
<xs:element name="main-contact">
    <xs:complexType>
        <xs:sequence>
            <xs:choice>
                <xs:element name="person">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:group ref="person"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
                <xs:element name="company">
                    <xs:complexType>
                        <xs:group ref="company"/>
                    </xs:complexType>
                </xs:element>
            </xs:choice>
            <xs:group ref="contact"/>
        </xs:sequence>
    </xs:complexType>
</xs:element>

<xs:group name="person">
    <xs:sequence>
        <xs:element name="title" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="salutation" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="forename" minOccurs="0"/>
        <xs:element name="surname">
        </xs:element>
        <xs:element name="birthdate" type="xs:date" minOccurs="0"/>
    </xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="company">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="name"/>
    <xs:element name="phone">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="fax" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[0-9]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="e-mail" minOccurs="0">
        <xs:simpleType>
            <xs:restriction base="xs:string">
                <xs:pattern value="[a-z | A-Z | 0-9 | . | -]+@[a-z | A-Z | 0-9 | . | -]+[.][a-z | A-Z | 0-9 | . | -]+"/>
            </xs:restriction>
        </xs:simpleType>
    </xs:element>
    <xs:element name="website" type="xs:string" minOccurs="0">
    </xs:element>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>

<xs:group name="contact">
<xs:sequence>
    <xs:element name="phone-private" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="phone-office" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="fax-private" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="fax-office" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="e-mail-private" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="e-mail-office" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
    <xs:element name="website" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
</xs:sequence>
</xs:group>
```

XSD.exe created Object class:

```
[System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("xsd", "4.0.30319.33440")]
[System.SerializableAttribute()]
[System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute()]
[System.ComponentModel.DesignerCategoryAttribute("code")]
[System.Xml.Serialization.XmlTypeAttribute(AnonymousType = true)]
public partial class exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontact
{

    private object itemField;

    private object[] phoneprivateField;

    private object[] phoneofficeField;

    private object[] faxprivateField;

    private object[] faxofficeField;

    private object[] emailprivateField;

    private object[] emailofficeField;

    private object[] websiteField;


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("company", typeof(exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactCompany))]
    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("person", typeof(exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontactPerson))]
    public object Item
    {
        get
        {
            return this.itemField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.itemField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("phone-private")]
    public object[] phoneprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneprivateField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("phone-office")]
    public object[] phoneoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.phoneofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.phoneofficeField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fax-private")]
    public object[] faxprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxprivateField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("fax-office")]
    public object[] faxoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.faxofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.faxofficeField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("e-mail-private")]
    public object[] emailprivate
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailprivateField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailprivateField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("e-mail-office")]
    public object[] emailoffice
    {
        get
        {
            return this.emailofficeField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.emailofficeField = value;
        }
    }


    [System.Xml.Serialization.XmlElementAttribute("website")]
    public object[] website
    {
        get
        {
            return this.websiteField;
        }
        set
        {
            this.websiteField = value;
        }
    }
}
```

Where I'm stuck is how exactly i can initialize the 'Maincontact' element and it's sub elements, so far I've got to this point with initializing the class:

```
export.design = new exportDesign
{
    commission = new exportDesignCommission
    {
        dateofcreation = DateTime.Now,
        dateoflastchange = DateTime.Now,
        customer = new exportDesignCommissionCustomer
        {
            maincontact = new exportDesignCommissionCustomerMaincontact
            {
                //Initialisation in question to go here
            }
        }
    },
};
```

This may be fairly basic but i can't see how this initialisation would work based on a conditional choice to reflect the XSD choice. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Thanks and thanks again for reading this far :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All tools for generating code from `xsd` are not perfect and for complex xsd's you need to add some code by yourself. I better recommended for you to use [xsd2code](https://xsd2code.codeplex.com/) because of its customizability.

[Look at that blog](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mcsuksoldev/2012/10/26/dealing-with-an-xsd-choice-when-xsd-exe-doesnt-add-xmlchoiceidentifierattribute/) Here Simon Middlemiss answering your question.

Comment: Thanks, i've modified the generated XSD object class and all works fine. I'll post up a follow up here as I fear a fair few dev's have had this frustration.